# why is kindle ebook content not displaying properly after windows 10 update

Tags: kindle, image, windows

I'm using Kindle app for PCs on several windows OS devices, including Windows 7, 8.1, and 10.
After one of the Windows 10 machines did a recent update to latest build, the Kindle app started displaying the eBook content/images in an illegible way- appears to be a rectangle diagonally split from upper left to lower right, and the content looks like it's reflected across the diagonal while the paragraphs display correctly to the diagonal, then they run down the page to the right of diagonal. It's like the page was folded along the diagonal and the ink of print was wet, so it copied to other side of page.

I had this problem a week or two prior on one of the other machines after downloading a new eBook, but it was the only book that was jumbled up. The others in the library displayed fine. I don't remember which OS it was, but the fix was simply removing the eBook and/or the Kindle app, and then reloading it.  The kindle app on the updated Windows 10 is not displaying any of the books correctly, and removing and reloading the library and app has been no help.

Preliminary searches on Kindle's support and community doesn't mention it, and I haven't had any luck with basic Internet searches on the subject.

Anybody else seen/experienced this? Any known fixes?

[image: kindleTextImage]

Comment: I cannot help but have the exact same problem. Reinstalling and messing with video settings hasn't helped. Amazon is no help. They broke something.

Comment: I have the same problem. Amazon was no help! Hours of wasted time. No problem with app on my other devices but I get the same diagonal configuration on my pc. I hope someone has an answer.